# Runtime Error, Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm getting this error message when building the application. Please help me fix this.

[image]

This is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { firebase } from 'firebase';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

     firebase.initializeApp({
       apiKey: "AIzaSyClMdXK3nVurFhGepjfUSN49hEjFEb0xn0",
       authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
       storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "832108974830"
     });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

The error popped up after importing firebase and it's dependencies. I'm working on this error for more than 24 hours now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: can you share the code of `app.component.ts` file?

Comment: Please provide more details about you error